# pass the selected value of Html.DropDownList to controller

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I have a drop down in my view page. Since the drop down has only two values and it will not change so we decided to create static drop down.

```
@Html.DropDownList("RelationshipWithFather", new List<SelectListItem>()
 {
   new SelectListItem() { Text= "son", Value = "son" },
   new SelectListItem() { Text= "daughter", Value = "daughter" }
 }, "relationship...", new { @class = "form-control" })
```

How to pass the selected value of this `RelationshipWithFather` drop down to create controller method.

```
public ActionResult Create(PatientInfo vdm_)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                PatientInfo vdm = new PatientInfo();
                vdm.relationshipWithPatient = // selected value of RelationshipWithFather
            
            
            }
        }
```

I have to set the value of the selected dropdown to the `relationshipWithPatient` attribute of the model class.

Comment: If you check the docs, you'll see, that SelectListItem has property Selected.

https://learn.microsoft.com/pl-pl/dotnet/api/system.web.mvc.selectlistitem?view=aspnet-mvc-5.2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use DropDownListFor

```
@model PatientInfo
....

@{
 var items= new List<SelectListItem>()
 {
   new SelectListItem() { Text= "son", Value = "son" },
   new SelectListItem() { Text= "daughter", Value = "daughter" }
 };
}

@using (Html.BeginForm()) {

@Html.DropDownListFor (model=>model.relationshipWithPatient, items , "relationship...", new { @class = "form-control" })

}
```

or I prefer

```
<select class="form-control" asp-for="@Model.relationshipWithPatient" asp-items="@items"></select>
```

action

```
public ActionResult Create(PatientInfo vdm)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
      var selected=  vdm.relationshipWithPatient; //selected value of RelationshipWithFather
.....
   }
}
```